# How install MathNet.Symbolics in ASP.NET 4.8

Tags: asp.net, nuget-package, mathnet-numerics, mathnet-filtering

I have an application in ASP.NET on .NET 4.8, when I install nuget package `MathNet.Symbolics` I get this error:

> Can't find a version of 'FParsec' compatible with 'MathNet.Symbolics 0.25.0 restriction: FParsec (>= 2.0.0-beta2)'

Please help. Thanks

I try add reference library one to one but that didn't work, I am expecting to install, because in .NET Core install complete and ok, but I need it for .NET framework, this does not install.